# modifiable arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

So, I know some Python but I thought that I should try to add some c++ to that knowledge. This is the code I've written that I'm playing with (it's actually a rewrite of some python code). It adds some song data to a class (or a multidimensional array inside a class). So far so good. Most of it work. But I'm stuck at the `delSong` method. I don't think I could implement this with arrays, so It's seems like I'm at a dead end. I read a little about vectors, but they won't let med delete an item in the middle. How could I get further? Shall I abandon arrays for something else? But what would that be?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Jukebox{
public:
  void addSong(string artist, string title, string filename) {
    songs [songsCounter][0] = artist;
    songs [songsCounter][1] = title;
    songs [songsCounter][2] = filename;
    songsCounter++;
  }

  void printSong (int song) {
    cout << songs[song][0] << " - ";
    cout << songs[song][1] << " : ";
    cout << songs[song][2] << endl;
  }

  void printSongs () {
    int song;
    for (song=0; song<songsCounter; song++ ) {
      cout << songs[song][0] << " - ";
      cout << songs[song][1] << " : ";
      cout << songs[song][2] << endl;
    }
  }

  void delSong(int song) {
    // Some code here
  }

private:
  int songsCounter;
  string songs [512][3];
};

int main() {
  Jukebox jbox;
  jbox.addSong("U2", "Magnificent", "U2-Magnificent.mp3");
  jbox.addSong("Sting", "Englishman in New York", "Sting-Englishman_in_New_York.mp3");
  jbox.addSong("U2", "One", "U2-One.mp3");
  jbox.printSongs();
  return 0;
}
```

In my python code I actually using an in memory sqlite3 db. But I could as well write it with a simple list of tuples. And that is a similar approach to what I'm trying to do here. But an in memory sqlite database would also be a possible way for me to do this in c++. But it does'nt look very easy either to implement?

One more thing, I also want to add a sort method later so please have that in mind when you suggest a solution so I don't get to another dead end... :)

Comment: Vectors do allow deletion in the middle (look for the `erase` function), albeit not at the greatest speed. Btw, I'd recomend using `struct song { string artist; string title; string filename; };`  and then `std::vector<song> songs`instead of a multidimensional array.

Comment: It does? Then that page I read the other night was lying ;) Thnx...

Comment: What about sorting? (I added a paragraph at the end of my question)

Comment: You should read up on the standard library :) There's a `std::sort` function in the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: Ok. great. Thanks. If you want you could copy and paste this to an answer and I will accept it when I get it to work :)

Comment: Vectors of Songs is a nice way to go. If you use the STL properly and make functions when appropriate, you can almost feel like you're writing python. haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectors do allow deletion in the middle (look for the `erase` function), albeit not at the greatest speed.

I'd recomend using a vector of structures instead of a multidimensional array.

```
struct song {
    string artist;
    string title;
    string filename;
};
```

And then in your `Jukebox`:

```
vector<song> songs;
```

The vector grows as needed and keeps track of its own size, contrary to the array.

For sorting, there's `std::sort` function in the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: Oh. That's great. Having done a little Python programming I thought using a counter was really ugly when I in Python only would have just written `songs.append(song)` to add a song to the list and `len(songs)` to get the right number of songs in that list...

Comment: I hav'nt got the time to implement it yet (just started). I have to learn more about vectors and structs before I go one. But from what I read this really seems to be the way to go. Also saw a question on Stack Overflow about sorting a vector of structs. Anyway, a big thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, add a constructor

> Jukebox()
>      {
>          //do initialization here
>      }

You can delete a middle item in a vector.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/

> ```
>  vector<unsigned int> myvector;
>
>  // set some values (from 1 to 10)
>  for (i=1; i<=10; i++) 
>       myvector.push_back(i);
>
>  // erase the 6th element
>  myvector.erase (myvector.begin()+5);
> ```

Another approach, with the least code modification would be to move all the songs FOLLOWING the song to be deleted to the left by 1 and then decrement songCounter.

```
//Assuming song 1 is the song at index 0 and songCounter points to the first  
//empty element in the array  
//ex: 1,2,3,4,5 becomes 1,3,4,5
void delSong(int song) {  
    if(song <= 0) return;  
    if(song < songCounter-1) //we don't want to delete song 500 if we only have 20   
    {  
        song--;
        while (song != songCounter)
        {
            songs[song][0] = songs[song+1][0];
            songs[song][1] = songs[song+1][1];  
            songs[song][2] = songs[song+1][2];
            song++;
        }
    }  
    //this handles case of deleting the last song in addition to the above case
    if(song < songCounter)  
    {  
        songCounter--;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I check that out as fast as I get around to it. Now I have to get my kid some food ;)